# Does a non-American need an ESTA to leave the USA?

Tags: visas, air-travel, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I am a British Citizen who will be travelling to Canada and then onwards to USA by train and then returning to Canada by air. I am aware that I do not need an ESTA to enter the USA by train but do I need any documents when traveling back from the USA to Canada by Air? I will be flying home to the UK a few days after returning to Canada. I am only spending a week in Canada and a week in the USA.

To clarify, the travel plans looks like this:

- Fly UK to Canada
- Train from Canada to USA (Vancouver to Seattle)
- Domestic flight from Portland to San Francisco
- Flight from San Francisco to Vancouver
- Return to UK from Canada

## edit

So, after taking the trip I can confirm that you can travel by train from Canada to the states without an ESTA but it's a bit of a hassle (paperwork, fingerprints, payment must be in USD) and it would have been easier to just get an ESTA. Returning to Canada from the US wasn't an issue.

Comment: Suggest you leave your vacation photos of Yemen, North Korea etc. (if you have any) at home: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/niels-gerson-lohman/us-border-crossing_b_4098130.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Firstly, note that you'll likely be required to get a visa at the border with the US, even though you're in the visa-waiver countries for ESTA - it apparently only counts for flights, or within 90 days of a flight into the US if arriving by land(!) as I found out, twice.

However, leaving the country there's not even a passport check - you simply need to have the legal (visa or other requirements depending on your passport) for entering the next country. As the country for you is Canada, and you're a British citizen, [you're visa exempt for travel to Canada](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/visas/passports_brit_passeports.aspx).

Documents-wise, you'll need your passport and travel documents (flights etc) and it's handy to have any details of your accommodation or other travel plans, in case you get asked for them at any of the borders.

Comment: (+1) Isn't there a card to hand in or something like that when you enter or leave through a land border?

Comment: @Relaxed [Yup, the I-94](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/returning-uncollected-i94-form-to-cbp.html) and it's a pain in the butt trying to get a Canadian official to accept it, or even Greyhound, despite what the linked page says about it.

Comment: There are no longer paper I-94's in use

Comment: @andrewmh20 at land borders there are (as recently as a few months ago, I had to use one!)

Comment: @MarkMayo what if you arrive by air and leave by land?

Comment: @andrewmh20 then you just go through the border happily.

Comment: @andrewmh20 That is likely going to be problematic, because when entering by land and exiting by land or air, the departure is recorded through the green I94W form handed in to the Canadian official or the Airline. However, if entering by air (and thus not getting a green form) and exiting by land, there's literally no way for them to record it. In this case, there is a dedicated address in Ohio you should send all your evidence of departing the US to.

Comment: This has changed: [Effective October 1, 2022, all Visa Waiver Program (VWP) travelers intending to enter the United States by land will be required to obtain an approved Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA) prior to application for admission at land border ports of entry.](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1258?language=en_US)  (Also, in US terminology, neither ESTA nor the I-94 form is a visa, and there's no such thing as a "visa at the border."  A visa is issued by the State Department; the State Department has no officers at ports of entry.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a British Citizen who have travelled between Canada and USA.

The ETSA is only for flights as you rightly said.

If I drive through the border, then I must stop at USA Immigrations and pay $6, fill in quick form, and have my fingerprints taken. I have not done this via the train so I don't know how that part works.

As for entering Canada, shouldn't be too much hassle especially if you have a return ticket home to show that you are simply a tourist.

Best of luck!

Comment: Nowadays, visa-exempt air travelers to Canada need to get eta (Canada's answer to ESTA).  US citizens are exempt even from eta, however, just as Canadians are exempt from ESTA.

Comment: Technically, the ESTA is not required for a "land crossing".  But as it happens, CBP doesn't consider the Amtrak Cascades train from Vancouver to Seattle to be a "land crossing", meaning that an ESTA is required for the journey.  See [this answer.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/104191/31165)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert This has changed: [Effective October 1, 2022, all Visa Waiver Program (VWP) travelers intending to enter the United States by land will be required to obtain an approved Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA) prior to application for admission at land border ports of entry.](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1258?language=en_US)  But they still seem to have the option to get a provisional I-94 through the web site for land border crossings.  Someone should ask/answer a question about how the process now works.