# Does an American citizen need an ESTA to leave the United States?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, esta

I am an American citizen, looking to fly to the EU. I am feeling I do not need an ESTA because the wording implies the necessity of the document belongs to non-US citizens. May be an obvious question, but I would like to be sure. I wouldn't want to ruin plans due to a misstep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need an ESTA to leave the USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35372/do-i-need-an-esta-to-leave-the-usa)

Comment: You don't need an ESTA if you are an American regardless if you are entering or leaving.  The [guidance](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) says 'international travellers' but it really means 'foreigners who are coming to the US'

Comment: Several of the flights I have booked have just said I should apply for an ESTA if entering or leaving—no mention of "international travellers."

Comment: No ESTA but January 2021 you will need ETIAS for Eurooe. https://www.etiasvisa.com/etias-news/etias-europe

Comment: @SeanBanks that site is yet another of the unofficial sites that seek to exploit travelers by pretending to be official and then overcharging them for the so-called "service" of processing their travel authorization application on their behalf.  As is common with these sites, its information is obsolete and outdated.  Last July, the EU was saying that ETIAS was ["expected" to be operational in "early 2021,"](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-18-4362_en.htm).

Comment: @SeanBanks but in October, they said it would be [online in late 2021 and fully operational in 2022](https://www.eulisa.europa.eu/Newsroom/News/Pages/ETIAS-Regulation-enters-into-force.aspx).  As with any large government project, the prospect of its being completed according to the anticipated schedule is perhaps somewhat low.  But it is fairly clear that it is better to stick to official sources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right. The  ESTA is needed only for citizens of certain non-US countries who want to visit the US under the Visa Waiver Program.

The US doesn't require authorization, permission or registration for *anyone* trying to *leave* the  country. And as a US citizen, you also don't need permission to come back, just your passport.

(When you  fly back to the US, there is a process called APIS by which your airline will let the US government know who is coming. So your airline will ask for your passport details at some point before your return flight, either at check-in or online. But other than  that, no action is required from you.)

Comment: And when you return to the US, you can do passport control [from your smartphone](http://mobilepassport.us/) after you land, and then follow the Mobile Passport Control signs to skip the lines and go straight to baggage claim and customs.

Comment: *"And as a US citizen, you also don't need permission to come back" -- unless you're on the no-fly list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Fly_List

Comment: @jpatokal Even then, that's just to fly back. You can come back by land or sea without advance permission.