# Why do they keep asking for an ESTA when leaving the USA?

Tags: usa, airlines, esta

Americans do not need an ESTA to enter USA, and no one needs it to leave¹.  Yet every time I've booked a flight in recent years, I've been told (I ignore it) that I need an ESTA for flights to/from the United States.  It never says anything about citizenship, and it always says "to/**from**."  Several airlines from different countries.

Are they all copying standard text written by someone unqualified or lazy?

Per one request, here's an example: [image]

¹[Does an American citizen need an ESTA to leave the United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53179/does-an-american-citizen-need-an-esta-to-leave-the-united-states)

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing who is telling you this...

Comment: Delta, Norwegian, Iberia, American, United, … as I said, most if not all of my dozens of flights the past couple of years.

Comment: Can you link or copy/paste an example?

Comment: Exactly how are you being asked this?

Comment: While I'm still thinking about this, are you a dual citizen traveling on your other (non-US) passport, or have given the other passport number to the airline in the past?

Comment: I am a citizen only of USA at present.  Almost every airline or other website I have used to buy tickets has had words like that.  Even if I did need an ESTA to enter, no one needs it to leave.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of a page which has this requirement. Closing as unclear until then.

Comment: I looked at a couple of the mentioned airlines' pages on documents (American and Iberia), and they both correctly associated ESTA with the VWP and mentioned it in connection with travel *to* the United States. I therefore agree with other commenters: Without reference to a specific instruction concerning ESTA, it is not possible to answer the question.  They were indeed somewhat imprecise in varying ways, but they did not amount to a blanket statement that all travelers flying to or from the US require ESTA.

Comment: Can’t do a screenshot till the next time I am buying tickets.  It always shows up at the end.

Comment: I think the most recent was Norwegian.

Comment: Typically airlines have some standard texts along the lines of "make sure you have the proper documents, or we won't allow you to board". It is possible that some automated systems add the line about ESTAs as soon as they detect a segment ending in the US, as they cannot see your nationality in the reservation (you don't enter it when booking and the Advanced Passenger Information that you enter before departure does not end up linked to it).

Comment: That may be, but the question is about why so many say you need an ESTA to leave, which is never true of anyone.

Comment: Unclear?  It STARTS with "Why do they keep asking for an ESTA when _leaving_ USA?"  How is that unclear?!?

Comment: Thanks for adding the image.  It'd be nice if you'd state the source in the question.

Comment: At least for the "Americans" part, the text seems to be correct: it refers to "all passengers eligible to travel under the Visa Waiver Program", which US citizens aren't.  Confusing maybe, since many US citizens may not know that, but not wrong.  I agree that the "from" in "to/from" seems to be wrong.

Comment: One could argue, that "from" means, if you book a return flight from the USA, where you then need a valid ESTA for the return portion (a little bit far fetched if that's the real reason and also confusing, but still possible). Such notice at the time of checkin for the return flight would be too late, given the fact that ESTAs are not necessarily approved immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your screenshot is from the Norwegian booking process. Searching around, you're not the first person to wonder about this. The [Norwegian background info page](https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/check-in-and-boarding/passport-visa/) seems to have it right:

> ## Travelling to the U.S. (ESTA)
>
> The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) allows citizens of countries that are
>   members of the VWP to travel **to** the U.S. without applying for a
>   specific visa. It is, however, a requirement of the U.S. Department of
>   Homeland Security for all passengers eligible to travel under the VWP
>   to apply for an Electronic System Travel Authorisation (ESTA).

but it would appear that the booking process is less intelligent about the whole from / to thing. [One traveller reports getting an answer from Norwegian customer service](https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/england/norwegian-air-requiring-visa-waiver-what-to-do#945055):

> I got this answer from Norwegian today in response to my question on
>   their facebook page.
>
> > Norwegian
> >
> > Hi.
> >
> > This is only a reminder for the passengers who need to apply for the
> >     ESTA.
> >
> > Best regards
> >
> > Lene

So, in answer to your question

> Are they all copying standard text written by someone unqualified or lazy?

Sort of. They are applying standard text regardless of whether it is relevant or not.